# i can not use attributes while using ejs. <%= item.name %> ".name" part is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to export datas from mongodb and even I add the attribute of my data, I can not receive what I want. I am just a rookie and I couldn't find the solution on web

```js
<%newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p> <%= item.name %> </p>
    </div>
<% })  %>
```

This is my code and ".name" part is not working. How can I figure it out?